# Autowrap text in another shape than rectangle

Tags: text, figma

Is it possible to wrap the text into another shape than the rectangle? I want to write the text inside the triangle frame and the words to wrap automatically. Additionally, the diagonal is on the left, so it would have to be the beginning of the line that is adjusted, not the end of the line.